Transaction fees on Phantom
I want to transfer ETH from my Ledger hard wallet to Phantom. Will I have to pay the fees for this transaction in SOL or in ETH? There is only a little amount of ETH left on my Phantom Wallet, and I want to avoid the procedure of buying it over the Wallet via debit card. Thank you.

Phantom is multi-chain and you will only pay tx fees for the chain you are using. If you are using Ethereum you'll pay Ethereum gas fees and if Solana you'll pay Solana tx fees.
If you have some Sol, you can bridge these funds to your desired chain. Find the best rates using Jupiter -> https://jup.ag/bridge/compare

Thank you, mate.
